# Access URL in SAS and stored data in dataset and JSON file

Tags: json, sas, sas-macro

I am trying to access a URL and want to store data into a dataset and output file as JSON..

I just want to fetch URL data and store as a JSON file
But my question has two part......

1. If url response data is already as a json format like
   http://headers.jsontest.com then i just use `file` command and `put`
   command with `json` extension
2. If the url response data is `html tags` like any other url data
   then can it be parsed or converted to `json` format by SAS

I have tried to fetch suppose http://www.google.com or http://headers.jsontest.com.... here is my code.....

```
LIBNAME src '/home/user/readURL';
filename test_url url 'http://headers.jsontest.com' debug lrecl=8192;
    data src.http;
        infile test_url length=len;
        input record $varying8192. len;
        file '/home/user/readURL/READ_URL.txt';
        put test_url;
    run;
proc print data = src.http;
run;
```

This is the log file with error message i got after executing my code : **ERROR: The connection has timed out..**

Any idea how to get rid of this.....

```
2  The SAS System   07:57 Wednesday, January 15, 2014

16         filename test_url url 'http://headers.jsontest.com' debug lrecl=8192;
17         data src.http;
18         infile test_url length=len;
19         input record $varying8192. len;
20         run;

ERROR: The connection has timed out..
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: SAS set option OBS=0 and will continue to check statements. This may cause NOTE: No observations in data set.
WARNING: The data set SRC.HTTP may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 1 variables.
WARNING: Data set SRC.HTTP was not replaced because this step was stopped.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           1:14.92
      cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

and got `READ_URL.txt` as a blank file

Thanks for any help in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have resolved my own problem but only 1st part .... if anybody found this type of similar error (**ERROR: The connection has timed out..**)...try to use `proxy` over there....like I have added in my code....

```
LIBNAME src '/home/user/readURL';

filename test_url url 'http://headers.jsontest.com' debug lrecl=8192 PROXY='http://hostname:portno/';
data src.http;
    infile test_url length=len;
    input record $varying8192. len;
    file '/home/user/readURL/READ_URL.json';
    put record;
run; 

proc print data = src.http;
run;
```

But still I have to resolve my 2nd part of question....

Comment: I'd post that in a second question, with information on what the file looks like.  These two parts are too different to be in one SO question.